# Django - Select MAX of field of related query set

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Say if I have models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = ...
    dob = ...

class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

And I want to query all Users and annotate with both Count of events and MAX of Events.timestamp

I know for count I can do:

```
Users.objects.all().annotate(event_count=models.Count('event_set'))
```

But how do I do max of a related queryset field? I want it to be a single query, like:

> SELECT Users.*, MAX(Events.timestamp), COUNT(Events)
>   FROM Users JOIN Events on Users.id = Events.user_id

Comment: you can use `.annotate` and `.aggregate` on query like `Users.objects.all().annotate().annotate()`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to achieve that. You might have to play around with the foreign key related name depending on your code, but it would result in something looking like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Func,

Users.objects.all().annotate(
    event_count=Count('event_set'), 
    max_timestamp=Func(F('event_set__timestamp'), function='MAX')
)
```

Comment: Ok so you can chain field names onto the reverse-related query set.. also wouldn't this just simplify to Max('event_set__timestamp')?

Comment: Yes, since you do not perform any other operations using the fields it should also work to just call `Max('event_set__timestamp')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an aggregate query for this as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Users.objects.all().aggregate(Max('Events.timestamp'))
```

See details for the above code in Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: This would just get a single result which is the max Events.timestamp value, not a sequence of annotated User objects. Also syntax should be double-underscore not dot?